# Styling HTML5 Video Controls

Tags: css, html5-video

I can't seem to get the styling correct on the video player controls as nothing seems to align correctly.

I've tried wrapping the items in divs, and lis but things just don't seem to move or align correctly.

Any suggestions?

What i have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/pp6Wn/

```js
var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn;

function intializePlayer() {
  // Set object references
  vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
  playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
  seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
  curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
  durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
  mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
  volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
  fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
  // Add event listeners
  playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
  seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
  vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
  volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);
  fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen, false);
}
window.onload = intializePlayer;

function playPause() {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)";
    playbtn.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)";
    playbtn.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
  }
}

function vidSeek() {
  var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
  vid.currentTime = seekto;
}

function seektimeupdate() {
  var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
  seekslider.value = nt;
  var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
  var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
  var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
  var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);
  if (cursecs < 10) {
    cursecs = "0" + cursecs;
  }
  if (dursecs < 10) {
    dursecs = "0" + dursecs;
  }
  if (curmins < 10) {
    curmins = "0" + curmins;
  }
  if (durmins < 10) {
    durmins = "0" + durmins;
  }
  curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
  durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
}

function vidmute() {
  if (vid.muted) {
    vid.muted = false;
    mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
  } else {
    vid.muted = true;
    mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
  }
}

function setvolume() {
  vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
}

function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (vid.requestFullScreen) {
    vid.requestFullScreen();
  } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
```

```css
#video-container,
#playpausebtn,
#fullscreenbtn,
#mutebtn,
#curtimetext,
#durtimetext,
#seekslider,
#volumeslider {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#video-container {
  position: relative;
}
div#video_controls_bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #61676D;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 5% auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
#video-container:hover #video_controls_bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
button#playpausebtn {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 7%;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
button#playpausebtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
button#fullscreenbtn {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdG9yOiBBZG9iZSBJbGx1c3RyYXRvciAxNS4xLjAsIFNWRyBFeHBvcnQgUGx1Zy1JbiAuIFNWRyBWZXJzaW9uOiA2LjAwIEJ1aWxkIDApICAtLT4NCjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+DQo8c3ZnIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgaWQ9IkxheWVyXzEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4Ig0KCSB3aWR0aD0iMThweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxOHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTggMTgiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDE4IDE4IiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj4NCjxnIG9wYWNpdHk9IjAuOTUiPg0KCTxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNGRkZGRkYiIGQ9Ik0xNy41LDEyLjU1MWMwLDAuMzg1LTAuMzE0LDAuNjk5LTAuNjk5LDAuNjk5aC0xLjM5MmMtMC4zODUsMC0wLjQ3NywwLjIyMy0wLjIwNCwwLjQ5M2wxLjgxMSwxLjgwNA0KCQljMC4yNzIsMC4yNzEsMC4yNzIsMC43MTcsMC4wMDIsMC45ODlsLTAuNTA3LDAuNTFjLTAuMjcxLDAuMjczLTAuNzE0LDAuMjczLTAuOTg1LDBsLTEuNzgzLTEuNzk3DQoJCWMtMC4yNzEtMC4yNzMtMC40OTItMC4xODMtMC40OTIsMC4yMDJ2MS4zNWMwLDAuMzg1LTAuMzE0LDAuNjk5LTAuNjk5LDAuNjk5aC0wLjcyNmMtMC4zODYsMC0wLjctMC4zMTQtMC43LTAuNjk5di00Ljk3Ng0KCQljMC0wLjM4NiwwLjMxNC0wLjcsMC43LTAuN2g0Ljk3NmMwLjM4NSwwLDAuNjk5LDAuMzE0LDAuNjk5LDAuN1YxMi41NTF6IE0wLjUsMTIuNTUxYzAsMC4zODUsMC4zMTQsMC42OTksMC42OTksMC42OTloMS4zNQ0KCQljMC4zODUsMCwwLjQ3NiwwLjIyMywwLjIwNSwwLjQ5NGwtMS44MDEsMS44MDNjLTAuMjcyLDAuMjcxLTAuMjcyLDAuNzE3LDAsMC45ODhsMC41MTQsMC41MTRjMC4yNzEsMC4yNzIsMC43MTcsMC4yNzIsMC45ODgsMA0KCQlsMS44MDEtMS44MDFjMC4yNzItMC4yNzIsMC40OTUtMC4xOCwwLjQ5NSwwLjIwNXYxLjM0OGMwLDAuMzg1LDAuMzE0LDAuNjk5LDAuNjk5LDAuNjk5aDAuNzI2YzAuMzg1LDAsMC43LTAuMzE0LDAuNy0wLjY5OXYtNC45NzYNCgkJYzAtMC4zODYtMC4zMTQtMC43LTAuNy0wLjdIMS4xOTljLTAuMzg1LDAtMC42OTksMC4zMTQtMC42OTksMC43VjEyLjU1MXogTTE3LjUsNS40NDljMC0wLjM4NS0wLjMxNC0wLjY5OS0wLjY5OS0wLjY5OWgtMS4zOTINCgkJYy0wLjM4NSwwLTAuNDc2LTAuMjIyLTAuMjAyLTAuNDkybDEuODA2LTEuNzg0YzAuMjczLTAuMjcxLDAuMjc0LTAuNzE0LDAuMDAxLTAuOTg0bC0wLjUtMC40OTcNCgkJYy0wLjI3Mi0wLjI3MS0wLjcxNy0wLjI2OS0wLjk4OCwwLjAwNGwtMS43ODMsMS43OTdDMTMuNDcyLDMuMDY3LDEzLjI1LDIuOTc2LDEzLjI1LDIuNTlWMS4xOTljMC0wLjM4NS0wLjMxNC0wLjY5OS0wLjY5OS0wLjY5OQ0KCQloLTAuNzI2Yy0wLjM4NiwwLTAuNywwLjMxNC0wLjcsMC42OTl2NC45NzZjMCwwLjM4NSwwLjMxNCwwLjcsMC43LDAuN2g0Ljk3NmMwLjM4NSwwLDAuNjk5LTAuMzE0LDAuNjk5LTAuN1Y1LjQ0OXogTTAuNSw2LjE3NQ0KCQljMCwwLjM4NSwwLjMxNCwwLjcsMC42OTksMC43aDQuOTc2YzAuMzg1LDAsMC43LTAuMzE0LDAuNy0wLjdWMS4xOTljMC0wLjM4NS0wLjMxNC0wLjY5OS0wLjctMC42OTlINS40NDkNCgkJQzUuMDY0LDAuNSw0Ljc1LDAuODE0LDQuNzUsMS4xOTlWMi41OWMwLDAuMzg1LTAuMjIyLDAuNDc4LTAuNDk1LDAuMjA1bC0xLjgwMS0xLjhDMi4xODMsMC43MjIsMS43MzYsMC43MjEsMS40NjIsMC45OTENCgkJbC0wLjUwNywwLjVjLTAuMjczLDAuMjctMC4yNzQsMC43MTMtMC4wMDEsMC45ODNsMS43OTgsMS43ODRDMy4wMjQsNC41MjgsMi45MzQsNC43NSwyLjU0OSw0Ljc1aC0xLjM1DQoJCUMwLjgxNCw0Ljc1LDAuNSw1LjA2NCwwLjUsNS40NDlWNi4xNzV6Ii8+DQo8L2c+DQo8L3N2Zz4NCg==);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 7%;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
button#mutebtn {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}
#curtimetext,
#durtimetext {
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input#seekslider {
  width: 35%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
input#volumeslider {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}
input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #384047;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #6CBB7C;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px transparent;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e74c3c;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px transparent;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #curtimetext,
  #durtimetext {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
  <video id="my_video" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="http://romain-menard.fr/cours_html5/sitedemo/src/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video/movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
  <!-- Video Controls -->
  <div id="video_controls_bar">
    <button id="playpausebtn"></button>

    <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"><span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
    <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
    <button id="fullscreenbtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the effect that i am aiming for

[image]

Comment: it works really well. it just need a few styling changes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle to fix this for you, you elements needed the following CSS added:

```
.class{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pp6Wn/2/

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex-box:

```
#video_controls_bar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // All items vertically centered.
}
```